# how to use jquery in included html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry for the title...
so i separated the index.html into divs then i called the contant using :

```
<script>$(function(){$("#work_bunch").load("wb.html"); });</script>
```

and it works fine but i wont to use jquery on the elements in wb.html
i used this in index :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="java_scripts/wb_op.js"></script>
```

what ever i write in the `.js` file it seems to work fine in the index
but i can't select any element in `wb.html`

for example (if img5 is an element wb.html) :

```
$("#img5").mouseover(function(){
  $(img5).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: Is that a typo or are you referencing and undefined local variable `img5` in the anonymous function?

Comment: i should have used ("#img5")..i got it wrong when i asked the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#element_in_wb_page', function() {
    // your function
});
```

In your case:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#img5', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use delegate method `on` if content added dynamically

```
$("#work_bunch").on("mouseover", "#img5", (function(){
  $(this).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

and typo issue `$(img5)` to       `$("#img5")`

Comment: Use "this" for current object

Comment: both are same things because according `w3c` `id` should be always unique, but thanks for suggestion when `op` duplicate id in html

Answer (score 1):

If you are including .js in head tag, then you need to make use `document.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#img5").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut(2000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Then please make a PLUNKER and share the URL.

Comment: i dont undersatnd you ;-;

Answer (score 1):

Delegate the event:

```
$("#work_bunch").on("mouseover", "#img5", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

---

When DOM was ready your elements were not there they come into view afterwards so at the time of DOM ready all the events were bound to existing elements. If any element is generated dynamically or put into the view via `ajax` any event will not be bound to them.

So the solution to cater this issue is to try to delegate the event to the closest static parent whenever possible, although you can delegate to `document` also but that is way expensive in lookup of that dom elements.

explaining syntax:

```
$(parentToDelegate).on(event, selector, callbackFn);
```

Comment: it doesnt work like that but it did when i replaced "#work_bunch" with document ;-;

Comment: would you take a look in here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338259/how-to-use-location-hash-and-trigger-to-navigate

Answer (score 1):

here is what i found to be more general solution
use

```
$(window).load(function() {
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
});
```

**because:**
- The document ready event executes already when the HTML-Document is loaded.
- The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images.